# RCTNetworking.clearCookies is not Supported in react native above 0.71?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, expo

I have been using this below piece of code to clear cookies every time i used axios to pass authorization credentials ,so that credentials are cleared by clearing cookies and reregister after every logout

But some how after updating reactnative to 0.72. RCTNetworking is never supported with an error

> ERROR  TypeError: RCTNetworking.clearCookies is not a function (it is
> undefined)

Any help would be highly appreciated , how can i either update this code to support udpated version of react native .

```js
const RCTNetworking = require("react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTNetworking");

RCTNetworking.clearCookies((result) => {
  console.log(result); //true if successfully cleared
});
```